# Is the function $f\left(x,y,z\right) = \left(e^{x^2}+y+z,x+e^{y^2}+z,x+y+e^{z^2}\right) $ One-to-one?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the function 
$$f\left(x,y,z\right) = \left(e^{x^2}+y+z,x+e^{y^2}+z,x+y+e^{z^2}\right).$$
Show that f is one-to-one function on some neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I tried to approach this problem by setting two points $p_1,p_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that $p_1 = \left(x_1,y_1,z_1\right) \space and\space p_2 = \left(x_2,y_2,z_2\right)$. Then I tried to prove $p_1$=$p_2$ if  $\space f\left(p_1\right) = f\left(p2\right)$. But after plugging in, I have no idea how to prove its injection. 
Please help me to deal with this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $J_f(x,y,z)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}2xe^{x^2}&1&1\\1&2ye^{y^2}&1\\1&1&2ze^{z^2}\end{array}\right)$ (Jacobian matrix). Then $det(J_f(x,y,z))=8xyze^{x^2+y^2+z^2}+2-2ye^{y^2}-2xe^{x^2}-2ze^{z^2}$. Therefore $det(J_f(0,0,0))=2\neq 0$.

By the Inverse Function Theorem, $f$ is invertible in some neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$. In particular, $f$ is one to one in that neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$.